# Select the highest value from mixed string/int column in SQLİTE

Tags: sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYjHf.png)
I have a string type field in SQLITE. I want to find the largest data in this field that starts with ABC- only.

```
        Call CONNECTİON("DATA.db")
        ADAPTER = New SQLiteDataAdapter("select max(cast((CASE WHEN [PAN_NO] NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN [PAN_NO] END) as int)) AS max_int_no from [PANEL]", CONN)
        TABLE = New System.Data.DataTable
        ADAPTER.Fill(CType(TABLE, System.Data.DataTable))
        DG_1.DataSource = TABLE.DefaultView
        CONN.Close()
        ADAPTER = Nothing
        TABLE = Nothing
```

When I apply this code, I get the result in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDLJ6.png)

What I want it to be is like the picture below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLpke.png)

Comment: `select max(pan_no) from panel where pan_no like 'ABC-%'`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you, I will let you know the results when I try it on my computer at work tomorrow.